# ES5, how to use promises in a loop

Tags: node.js, loops, promise

say command_arr.length === 2

When I run the following function *device_execute_command*. The execution message order is

```
finish one command
finish one command
has latest state?
has latest state?
```

I expect is:

```
finish one command
has latest state?
finish one command
has latest state?
```

Code

```
var device_execute_command = function(command_arr) {
  // This is the main loop
  var i = 0;
  for(i=0; i < command_arr.length; i++) {
    var command = command_arr[i];
    var command_id = command.command_id;

    device_run_single_command(command).then(function(command){
      console.log();
      console.log("finish one command");
      console.log(command);

      return is_device_has_latest_state(command);
    }).then(function(command_with_condi){
      console.log();
      console.log("has latest state?");
      console.log(command_with_condi);

    });


  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Promises are asynchronous, and simple for-loop is not going to pause next iteration in order to wait until previous has completed.

Instead, you should redesign you loop logic, and run the next iteration only once previous is done. For example, with IIFE you can do it like this:

```
var device_execute_command = function(command_arr) {

  var i = 0;

  (function next() {
    command_arr[i] && device_run_single_command(command_arr[i++]).then(function(command) {
        console.log();
        console.log("finish one command");
        console.log(command);
        return is_device_has_latest_state(command);
      })
      .then(function(command_with_condi) {
        console.log();
        console.log("has latest state?");
        console.log(command_with_condi);
      })
      .then(next);
  })();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to asynchronous nature of javascript. What you want is to execute the promises one by one. And this cannot be achieved by simply calling promises on loop iterations. The easiest way to achieve this is probably by using `bluebird` promise implementation which comes with lots of methods for promise execution flow control.

For example, sequential execution in your case can be achieved as:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.each(command_arr, function(command) {
  return device_run_single_command(command).then(function(command) {
    console.log();
    console.log("finish one command");
    console.log(command);    
    return is_device_has_latest_state(command);
  }).then(function(command_with_condi) {
    console.log();
    console.log("has latest state?");
    console.log(command_with_condi);    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, JavaScript promises are asynchronous in nature. So, after "device_run_single_command(command)" function is called, the for loop would move to the next iteration. Hence, the output observed.

In JavaScript, this problem can be solved through various mechanisms. The approaches suggested by Yerken and dfsq would definitely work. With the future arrival of async/await, you can solve the problem even by staying with your original for loop structure. For now, async/await can be used by using the babel compiler.

```
async function device_execute_command(command_arr) {
  // This is the main loop
  var i = 0;
  for(i=0; i < command_arr.length; i++) {
    var command = command_arr[i];
    var command_id = command.command_id;

    command = await device_run_single_command(command);
    console.log();
    console.log("finish one command");
    console.log(command);

    var command_with_condi = await is_device_has_latest_state(command);
    console.log();
    console.log("has latest state?");
    console.log(command_with_condi);

  }

}
```